# Using .org directive with data in .data section: In connection with ld

Tags: linux, ld, gnu-assembler, att

In my efforts to understand how to use the GNU binutils to build a simple boot loader using 
[gas](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/as/index.html) I have come across the question, how do you tell the linker where to put your data, in a file that uses .org to advance the location counter while keeping the file size at 512 bytes. I can't seem to find a way to do this.

The assembly program that tries to do this is:

```
# Author: Matthew Hoggan
# Date Created: Tuesday, Mar 6, 2012

.code16                      # Tell assembler to work in 16 bit mode
.section .data
msg:                         # Message to be printed to the screen
  .asciz "hello, world"

.section .text
.globl _start                # Help linker find start of program
_start:
  xor  %ax,  %ax             # Zero out ax register (ah used to specify bios function to Video Services) 
  movw %ax,  %ds             # Since ax is 0x00 0x00 use it to set data segment to 0
  mov  $msg, %si             # Use source index as pointer to string

loop:
  movb %ds:(%si), %al        # Pass data to BIOS function in low nibble of ax
  inc  %si                   # Advance the pointer
  or   %al, %al              # If byte stored in al is equal to zero then...
  jz   _hang                 # Zero signifies end of string
  call print_char            # Print current char in al
  jmp loop                   # Repeat

#
# Function that uses bios function calls
# to print char to screen
#
print_char:
  movb $0x0e, %ah             # Function to print a character to the screen
  movb $0x07, %bl             # color/style to use for the character
  int  $0x10                  # Video Service Request to Bios
  ret

#
# Function used as infinite loop
#
_hang:
  jmp  _hang

.org 510
.byte 0x55, 0xAA

.end
```

---

**UPDATE**
Using the following commands I get the following error:

```
mehoggan@mehoggan-laptop:~/Code/svn_scripts/assembly/bootloader/gas$ ld --oformat binary -o string string.o 
string.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x5): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.data'
```

Comment: Minimal example that generates this error and what it means: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32639540/895245 Repository with working boot sector + BIOS examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples

Comment: I think `.org` doesn't work the same way in GAS that it does in NASM.  Since GAS is always making a relocatable object file for the linker to fill in addresses, it has no use for absolute addresses.  That only comes in when you link with `-Ttext=0x7c00` or a linker script.

Comment: Related: [I can't understand why LD gives rilocazione (relocation) error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371505) for the necessary `as` and `ld` commands to use 32-bit mode, not the x86-64 default on a 64-bit system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of work you should write your own [linker script](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/binutils/ld_6.html). Just pass it to the linker with the `-T` option.

My script for an almost identical problem was:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;
    bootsec :
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.bss)
        endbootsec = .;
        . = 0x1FE;
        SHORT(0xAA55)
    }
    endbootsecw = endbootsec / 2;
    image = 0x1200;
}
```

With that trick you don't event need to put the `0x55 0xAA` in the assembler!

The `0x1000` at the beginning: Actually all the jumps are relative, so that is not used, but it is needed later for the jump into protected mode...

`endbootsecw`, `endbootsec` and `image` are symbols used elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I get: `a.ld:11 cannot move location counter backwards (from 0000000000001200 to 00000000000011fe)` with that linker script on Binutils 2.24.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: Well, it looks like you are overflowing your section. That is, your code ends in `0x1200` and then in the linker you are trying to move the pointer back to `0x11FE`, and that is not allowed. That may happen if you have too much code in your asm, or if you are doing my linker trick **and** the `.org` thing at the same time.

Comment: "are doing my linker trick and the .org thing at the same time" DOH!