# nasm,86_64,linux,"hello world" program. when link ,it says "relocation truncated to fit"

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

```
[section .data]
strHello db "Hello World"
STRLEN equ $-strHello
MessageLength equ 9
Message db "hi!!!!   "


[section .text]
global main
main:
mov edx,STRLEN;
mov ecx,strHello;
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 0x80


call DispStr


mov ebx,0   
mov eax,1   
int 0x80    


DispStr:      
  mov ax,MessageLength
  mov dh,0
  mul dh
  add ax,Message
  mov bp,ax 
  mov ax,ds
  mov es,ax 
  mov cx,MessageLength
  mov ax,01301h 
  mov bx,0007h
  mov dl,0
  int 10h
  ret
```

Compile and run:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 helloworld.asm -o helloworld.o
$ gcc -s -o helloworld helloworld.o
helloworld.o: In function `DispStr':
helloworld.asm:(.text+0x31): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.data'
collect2: ld return 1
```

Comment: Since I can't test without nasm, I can only point you [here](http://www.technovelty.org/c/relocation-truncated-to-fit-wtf.html).

Comment: Looks like you're trying to add a 64-bit address (`Message`) to a 16-bit register (`AX`), which obviously isn't going to fit. You could try something like  `add ax,(Message & 0xFFFF)`. Though it seems unlikely that using `int 10h/ah=13h` would work in 64-bit mode.

Comment: thank you Michael .but when compile it says :  '&' operator may only be applied to scalar values

Comment: Ok, the syntax might be slightly different. But like I said, trying to use a real mode interrupt in 64-bit mode (or even in 32-bit protected mode) is not going to work out-of-the-box. You could use something like libx86 if you really, _really_ need to use such an interrupt, but I doubt that.

Comment: thank you . I mean... which  interrupt do you mean?

Comment: The last one (`10h`).

Comment: by the way,may I ask you the difference between the two `int`?

Comment: `int 10h` is 16-bit code. `int 80h` is 32-bit code... but will still work in 64-bit code, I'm told - you'd want to use the 32-bit sys_call numbers (4 for sys_write). . 64-bit code would use `syscall`.

Comment: does `syscall` equal to BIOS-call? or syscall is a kind of linux-call?

Comment: `syscall` is an instruction. 64-bit Linux uses it to request kernel services... much as 32-bit Linux uses `int 80h`.

Comment: thank you Frank Kotler. So what is bios call ?

Comment: BIOS interrupts (I guess that's what you mean?) are a series of interrupts providing services  for screen, keyboard, disk, etc. They are 16-bit code, useful when the machine first boots, but once the CPU has been put in 32-bit protected mode or 64-bit "long mode" (done by your OS), they simply won't work. Can be emulated by "DosBox" if you insist on using them. I wouldn't.

Comment: @FrankKotler : That is true, but you can switch out of long mode or 32/16 bit protected mode to the other modes. On a multicore system you can in theory put one core into long mode and have another core run in real mode (Each core on a system once started will generally start in Real Mode)

Comment: @MichaelPetch hi Michael - we still chewing this bone? I expect it would be amusing programming one core in one mode and one core in another, no? :)

Answer (score 1):

This exact error happens because at:

```
add ax,Message
```

`ax` is only 16-bit wide, but `Message` is a 64-bit wide address, so it won't fit during relocation.

I have explained this error in detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32639540/895245

The solution in this case is to use a linker script as mentioned at: [Using .org directive with data in .data section: In connection with ld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596555/using-org-directive-with-data-in-data-section-in-connection-with-ld)

This repository contains working examples of boot sectors and BIOS: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in 64-bit mode, you won't be able to use BIOS functions (i.e. the `int 10h` instruction). Even if you could, BIOS uses a different addressing mechanism, so attempting to use the address of `Message` wouldn't work anyway.

Also, wouldn't the first 3 lines of the `DispStr` function zero out `ax`? (since you're multiplying by `dh`, which was just set to zero)

Comment: whatif `Message: db "hi!!!!   "` ?   in fact , in the code I copyed to here , the  `dh` is used as switch(dh)

Comment: by the way ,would you please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406054/how-to-change-jmp-and-popfd-to-64-bit-code