# I can't understand why LD gives rilocazione (relocation) error

Tags: assembly, linker, x86, ld, gnu-assembler

I wrote this little bootloader, but when I link it I get this error:

```
 boot.o: nella funzione "_start":
    (.text+0xa): rilocazione adattata per troncamento: R_X86_64_16 contro ".data"
```

In English the error is:

```
boot.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.data'
```

My linker command is:

```
ld -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary boot.o -o boot.bin
```

My bootloader code written in GNU assembler is:

```
    code16

.data
        prova: .string "questa è una prova"

.text
.globl _start

_start:

//now i try to print on the screen a string
//for do that i'm gonna to use int 0x10

mov $0x13,%ah
mov $0x0,%bh
mov $0x01,%bl
mov $20,%cx

push $[prova]

pop %es

int $0x10

jmp boot
boot:
.=_start+510


.byte 0x55
.byte 0xaa
```

Comment: `ld` wants to link 64 bit code. Try to add `-melf_i386` option.

Comment: Also surprised `code16` works. Usually you need a period in front like `.code16`. Even after successfully link with Jester's change your code won't work as you expect when it does run.

Comment: I highly recommend if you are doing a bootloader in GNU assembler that for simplicity sake you remove the `data` section and put your data in the `.text` section after the last piece of code and before the `.byte 0x55 .byte 0xaa`. `.=_start+510` is not doing what you think it is. Since you have this on the linker `-Ttext 0x7c00`, `_start` will have a value of 0x7c00 not 0x0000. `.=_start+510` will set the location counter to 0x7c00+510 which is not what you want. Try this instead `.space 510-(.-_start)`

Comment: I also think you have this wrong `jmp boot` followed by `boot:` . It seems you might have been trying to create an infinite loop. If so, remove those 2 lines and replace it with `boot: jmp boot`. Your original code would simply jump to the instruction after the `jmp` instruction and continue on. My example jumps to the beginning of the `jmp` instruction effectively putting the cpu in an infinite loop.

Comment: Your `int 0x10` related code to write a string out also won't work as expected. You need to put 0x0000 in the _ES_ register, and the offset of your string `prova` into the _BP_ register. Not sure `bl` is an attribute you will are looking for but it might be okay. You need to set _AX_ to $0x1300 to ensure that _AL_ is 0. _DH_ and _DL_ are the row and column values to start displaying at. You don't set them so you might just luck out and have the characters printed at the top left of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a better understanding of bootloader development. Although you are getting a linker error, even if you do manage to build the bootloader and put it in a floppy image, it won't run as expected. You can see my comments under your answer for some of the issues.

Since your question is just about the linker error, I am going to make an educated guess based on the error message you did get, that you also assembled with something like:

```
as boot.s -o boot.o
```

The name of your assembly file may be different, but the assembler command will be similar.

---

I'm not sure this was just a typo introduced when you copied your code to Stackoverflow but this line at the top of your bootloader code:

```
code16
```

Should be:

```
.code16
```

---

This error suggests that you are developing in a 64-bit environment:

```
boot.o: nella funzione "_start":
(.text+0xa): rilocazione adattata per troncamento: R_X86_64_16 contro ".data"
```

When using GNU Assembler and GNU Linker, you need to assemble your 16-bit bootloader code to 32-bit objects, and also link as 32-bit code. In a 64-bit development environment *AS* and *LD* generally default to generating 64-bit objects and executables, not 32-bit which is the cause of your problems.

Commands like these would probably solve your linker error:

```
as --32 boot.s -o boot.o
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext 0x7c00 --oformat=binary boot.o -o boot.bin
```

The first command assembles to a 32-bit ELF object using the `--32` option. The second links as 32-bit using `-melf_i386` option. This should eliminate your error.